# AWS - Create passwords for .passwd and .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, password-encryption

My .passwd file contains 2 usernames and 2 passwords.

userNameX:$apr1$F3EFwwfP$W4gD4e/W98FerHQWDErfX0
userNameY:$apr1$Nq21ft8f$CRW4OdeRDVLsLnFwFaXyE0

They have been automatically generated by the old server just providing username and clear password.
Now I have just moved to the AWS Elastic Beanstalk, these two usernames/passwords work very well, but I would like to create more users and passwords. How should I do?

Comment: Hopefully these are not the real passwords respectively hashes. Otherwise your site might already be compromised.

Comment: Since everything is already set up, you can look at [htpasswd - Manage user files for basic authentication](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/htpasswd.html)

Comment: Olaf, what do you mean by "Hopefully these are not the real passwords respectively hashes." Of course they are fake passwords. Do you mean they are too short?

Comment: Olaf, thank you, it worked on Terminal. Do you know how to make it on php? I would like to build a web GUI for my users, so they choose username and password, then I get the hash and I add it to the .passwd file.

Comment: If these were the real hashes, someone could take them and break into your system.

Comment: Maybe the framework you use already has some user administration module.

Comment: Olaf, I have found the way to add username/password on php: just using $output = shell_exec('htpasswd -nb username password');

Comment: You can do that, but this exposes the password. See for example, http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/78734/26493

Comment: I have got it. Thanks. Is any better and safe way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `htpasswd`, look at [htpasswd - Options](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/htpasswd.html#options).
There, you have the warning about password on the command line

> **-b**
>   Use batch mode; i.e., get the password from the command line rather than prompting for it. This option should be used with extreme care, **since the password is clearly visible** on the command line. For script use see the -i option. Available in 2.4.4 and later.

And the recommended option `-i`:

> **-i**
>   Read the password from stdin without verification (for script usage).

This way, you can pass the password through standard input through a pipe (e.g. [`popen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php)).

---

You can also look at some authentication module, depending on the language and web framework you use.